# Looking for OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, powerpc

I am trying to restore G5 Mac for audio recording purposes. I believe the hard drive has failed and I will need to replace it. My research on this computer shows the latest compatible OS X to be 10.5.8. Where can I find this OS X?

Comment: I assume you don't have access to the installation media the computer came with?

Comment: The os for mac computers is named Mac OS and not iOS. You will have to search ebay to find a install disk, if you don't have the original one.

Answer (score 3):

Contact Apple Care on the web at http://www.apple.com/support/contact/ or by phone and they will ship you replacement DVD for 10.5 if you have lost yours. You can also find them used on Ebay and such. Lastly, local vendors, a friend or Mac User group are all viable sources of a loaner DVD.

If you use Apple, don't pay for support and ask for an exemption in case the product is vintage or obsolete. Let them know you want to order replacement media. You will likely have to pay a fee for the disc, but not for talking to the support people to find out the price and availability of the replacement OS. Also, have the serial number of the Mac handy to ensure you get the correct original media.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159

Comment: Thank you for your help. The G5 was given to me and so I do not have the original disks. Apple sent me the DVD for Snow Leopard for my iMac and that worked well so I will look for a link to order 10.5
Thank you again

Comment: @MichaelRicketts I've added details on Apple's process and a link to the version of the DVD you'll need in case you want to shop around before contacting Apple.